# jQuery Table - Reference User Input Row Names and Values

Tags: jquery, reference, html-table

I have several tables which are generated by another application, which I have no control over. I am totally new to jQuery and ajax, and have only a limited knowledge of jsp. Two sample rows are:

```
<table class="sicknessForm">                  
<tr id="row_0" class="datarow">
 <td id="col_2"><input name="row_0-col_2"  class="tabcell" value="Injuries"></td>
 <td id="col_4"><input name="row_0-col_4"  class="tabcell" value="01"></td>
 <td id="col_5"><input name="row_0-col_5"  class="tabcell" value="2"></td>
 <td id="col_6"><input name="row_0-col_6"  class="tabcell" value="5"></td>
</tr>  

<tr id="row_1" class="datarow">
 <td id="col_2"><input name="row_1-col_2"  class="tabcell" value="Absences"></td>
 <td id="col_4"><input name="row_1-col_4"  class="tabcell" value="100"></td>
 <td id="col_5"><input name="row_1-col_5"  class="tabcell" value="102"></td>
 <td id="col_6"><input name="row_1-col_6"  class="tabcell" value="105"></td>
</tr>  
</table>
```

There are more rows and columns in the actual tables. What I need to do is to pass the ordered row information to the database, e.g.:
     Injuries, 1, 2, 5 ....
     Absences 100, 102, 105...

I can retrieve the values for each input using:

```
 $('#SicknessForm .userInput').each(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
 });
```

1. How can I loop through each row, get the value from the first column (Injuries) and place the data into an array to send to the server?
2. How do I reference the first row of each column to disable user input on it?

   ```
   $(:HowDoIReferenceThis).attr('disabled', '');
   ```
3. I need to validate that each cell is numeric, other than the first column. Any pointers on this (otherwise I can check it in my servlet), especially on how to loop through all valid input cells (everything except 'Injuries','Abences', ... cells).

Comment: You have no control over the markup at all?  I ask because that application is generating invalid HTML with repeated IDs.

Comment: That plus the unnecessary use of input fields as column headers.

Comment: The application that generates the table cells just iterates over the row and column data to generate the table. It cannot be set up so that some cells are input and some are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/imeno3/3

All in one ready to go!

```
$(function() {
    var row = [];
    $('.datarow').each(function(i) {
        row.push($('td input:eq(0)', this).val() + ' -> ');
        $('td input:gt(0)', this).each(function(e) {
            if (isNaN(this.value)) {
                $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            } else {
                row.push(this.value);
            }
        });
    });
    var send_to_ajax = row.join(' ');
});
```

**UPDATED 2**

in response to comment

```
  $('.tabcell').change(function() {
    if (isNaN(this.value)) { 
    $(this).css('background','red');
    } else {
    $(this).css('background','green');
    }
  });
```

Comment: So this function loops through each 'datarow' class, places the column 0 text into the row array, then for each cell greater than 0 and it checks to see if it's not a number. If it is not a number it disables the element, otherwise it adds it onto the end of the row array.<br />
Is there a way to change the color of the element, or remove it, when a non-number character is entered?
    $(this).empty();
or 
    $(this).css({background:'red'});

However, when I try these nothing happens when I enter a non-numeric value. Can I add an on-change event to each table element  or row?

Thanks
Vic

Comment: Thanks again aSeptik! I was just looking at the .change event function myself. I was going to attach it to the row class, but your method works. I think that it's probably better if the event is attached to the input element rather than the row element. Vic

Answer (score 0):

```
//question 1
$('.sicknessForm tr td:first-child input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

//question 2
var results = {}
$('.sicknessForm tr').each(function(){   
    var data = new Array();
    $(this).find('input:enabled').each(function(){
        data.push($(this).val());
    });
    results[$(this).find('input:disabled').val()]=data;
});
```

At this point the results object will contain properties pointing to each data point.

For question 3:

You can validate it here, or you could do in the inner each before pushing it onto those arrays.  As far as validating numbers a simple way might be:

```
if (/^\d+$/.test($(this).val())){
    //data is good
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle I made to mess around with your stuff:  http://jsfiddle.net/YVkTy/

Comment: Awesome Ryley. Thanks for the quick response. I hadn't heard of jsfiddle before, that's really cool! If you can, please leave it up for at least little while.

Comment: I have no idea how it works regarding that side of things - hopefully it won't be deleted indefinitely!